# When would one use the findNavController method by itself instead of NavHostFragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, android-viewmodel, android-architecture-navigation

I'm working on a tutorial for working with LiveData in Kotlin [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-live-data/index.html) and I've come to a point in the instructions where one of my fragments says to use the NavHostFragment like so:

```
    /**
     * Called when the game is finished
     */
    private fun gameFinished() {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Game has just finished.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        val action = GameFragmentDirections.actionGameToScore()
        action.score = viewModel.score.value?:0
        NavHostFragment.findNavController(this).navigate(action)
        viewModel.onGameFinishComplete()
    }
```

But then, I ended up setting up an Observer with a lambda function in it in another fragment, and they say to use findNavController by itself with no arguments in this section:

```
        viewModelFactory = ScoreViewModelFactory(ScoreFragmentArgs.fromBundle(requireArguments()).score)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(ScoreViewModel::class.java)
        // sets observer
        viewModel.score.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {newScore ->
            binding.scoreText.text = newScore.toString()
        })
        viewModel.eventPlayAgain.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {playAgain ->
            if(playAgain) {
                findNavController().navigate(ScoreFragmentDirections.actionRestart())
                viewModel.onPlayAgainComplete()
            }

        })
```

I'm not entirely sure why one would require the call to the static method of the NavHostFragment class with 'this' sent in as a context in the first piece of code, but why one is able to call the method alone in the second one. Does the Observer or the viewLifecycleOwner or the viewModel generate an implied context in this wrapped block or something?

Answer (score 2):

They are both same methods. Fragment's findNavController source code is

```
fun Fragment.findNavController(): NavController =
        NavHostFragment.findNavController(this)
```